# How to deserailise json array or json object with same key with help of jackson library

Tags: java, jackson

my server return json and am using Jackson for deserailise the response

in the response i have key called Car the value of the car may be an array or an object then how can define my class

Response

if more than object exist then array of object will return otherwise an object will return

{
"Car":"[{obj,obj,obj}]"
}

{
"Car":"obj"

}

Answer (score 0):

the json format you posted has no array only strings. the first is **car** the second is **[{obj,obj,obj}]**

The json should look like this: `{"Car":["","",""]}` and can be mapped to this java class:

```
public static class JsonTest extends Hashtable<String, List<String>> {
    public JsonTest(){};
}
```

your second json string is of a different format it should have the array notation too:

```
{ "Car":[ "" ] }
```

Comment: sorry the err in json {"Car":"[{""},{""}]"}